# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: bfloat16, float32, int32, uint32

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tpu, tensorflow2

Does any newer versions of 2.2 or higher support TPU with float64?   I'm using VGP which requires float64 for numeric stability.  i get the following error:

TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: bfloat16, float32, int32, uint32

Current TF does not based the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting)

Comment: The tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input), clearly states that it supports `float64`. Let me know, if you meant something else

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say TPU support for float64.